# Create a DLL from Exe

Tags: visual-c++, dll, file-io

I'm trying to find a solution for creating a DLL from an Exe in C++. I'm currently working on an IIS / Tomcat setup script and need to have a DLL hard coded in my code and have it written as a DLL file.

I have found when dealing with binary files, I should write them one character at a time like so:

```
ofstream fout;
char c[2000];
fout.open("isapi.dll", ios::binary);
for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
    fout << c[i];
```

The only problem is, how do I store (hard code) the contents of a DLL in my code to create this DLL in my setup script?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're just trying to *pack* the contents of DLL file inside your EXE file?  If so, the common way to do this is to use an [embedded resource](http://syedgakbar.wordpress.com/2007/11/07/embedding-dll-and-binary-files-in-the-executable-applications/).  But is there a reason why you're doing this by hand, instead of using some kind of setup-generation utility (e.g. NSIS, Inno Setup, WiX, etc.)?

Comment: Daniel: Thanks for your comment. I found a free packaging utility to include in a self extracting installer that I package with my application. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use decompiler.Many decomiler are free to download,by this you can reach atleast at the all function and parameter also.I think it should be useful.